# questions from vectors applications

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

suppose that  An boat captain wants to travel due south at 40 knots.  If the current is moving northwest at 16 knots, in what direction and magnitude should he work the engine?
here is given picture for simplify
[image]

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we represent north as positive on the $y$-axis and east as positive on the $x$-axis, then the vector which gives the velocity of the current is $\vec{v}=16 (\cos 135^\circ,\sin 135^\circ)$. If the ship's absolute velocity must be $(0,-40)$, and the ship's velocity relative to the water is $\vec{w}$, then we have $\vec{v}+\vec{w}=(0,-40)$.

This gives $\vec{w}=(0,-40)-\vec{v}=(-16\cos 135^\circ, -40-16\sin 135^\circ) \approx (11.32,-51,32)$. This has magnitude approximately $r\approx 52.55$ knots and angle $\theta \approx -77.57^\circ$. Here's a visual aid:

$\hskip 1.6 in$ [image]

Comment: i have question why 135?  (cos135,sin135)where 135 came from?thanks first of all for explanation

Comment: Angles are defined counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis, and I presume you understand what $90^\circ$ and $45^\circ$ angles look like. Since the water current direction is $45^\circ$ from the positive $y$-axis, and the positive $y$-axis is $90^\circ$ from the positive $x$-axis, that means the direction has an angle of $45^\circ+90^\circ=135^\circ$.